# Como criar elementos e adicionar atributos com o javascript puro?

Tags: javascript

Não sei o porque o meu teste está dando errado.

```js
var t = document.querySelector("#t");

var x = document.createElement('div');

var y = document.createAttribute("id");
y.value = "azul";
var b = document.createAttribute("class");
y.value = "bloco";

x.attributes.setNamedItem(y);
x.attributes.setNamedItem(b);

t.appendChild(x);
```

```css
#t{
  width: 300px;
  background: red;
 height: 300px; 
}
.bloco{
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  display: block; 
}
#verde{
   background: green;
}
#azul{
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="t">
  <div class="bloco" id="verde"></div>
  
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A forma correta de colocar atributos num elemento com Javascript puro é  [`setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute). Nesse caso irá adicionar o atributo se não existir ou apenas atualizar o seu valor caso já exista.

No seu exemplo ficaria assim:

```js
var t = document.querySelector("#t");
var x = document.createElement('div');

x.setAttribute("id", "azul"); //adicionar o atributo id com o valor azul
x.setAttribute("class", "bloco"); //adicionar o atributo class com o valor bloco

t.appendChild(x);
```

```css
#t{
  width: 300px;
  background: red;
 height: 300px; 
}
.bloco{
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  display: block; 
}
#verde{
   background: green;
}
#azul{
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="t">
  <div class="bloco" id="verde"></div>
</div>
```

Para manipular classes é no entanto mais aconselhável utilizar [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList), pois permite-lhe facilmente adicionar e/ou remover várias classes.

Nesse caso tem à sua disposição vários métodos tais como:

- `add` - para adicionar uma nova classe
- `remove` - para remover uma classe existente
- `contains` - para saber se determinada classe existe

Entre outros. Logo seria mais aconselhado no exemplo que tinha seria utilizar o `classList` com `add`:

```
x.classList.add("bloco");
```

Veja a funcionar:

```js
var t = document.querySelector("#t");
var x = document.createElement('div');

x.setAttribute("id", "azul"); //adicionar o atributo id com o valor azul
x.classList.add("bloco"); //a classe bloco

t.appendChild(x);
```

```css
#t{
  width: 300px;
  background: red;
 height: 300px; 
}
.bloco{
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  display: block; 
}
#verde{
   background: green;
}
#azul{
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="t">
  <div class="bloco" id="verde"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Acho que a sua abordagem está complicada para algo mais simples. Você pode atribuir os atributos desta forma mais simples:

```js
var t = document.querySelector("#t");
var x = document.createElement('div');
x.id = "azul"; // adiciono o id
x.className = "bloco"; // adiciono a classe

t.appendChild(x);
```

```css
#t{
  width: 300px;
  background: red;
 height: 300px; 
}
.bloco{
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  display: block; 
}
#verde{
   background: green;
}
#azul{
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="t">
   <div class="bloco" id="verde"></div>
</div>
```